# MongoDB: query performance with $match vs without $match

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

**Method-1**

```
db.getCollection('testColl').find({
    "car": { 
        "$elemMatch": {
            "brand": {
                "$in": [                    
                "bmw","audi"           
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**Method-2**

```
db.getCollection('testColl').find({
    "car.brand" :{$in : ["bmw","audi"]}
```

Both are returning the same result, but i was wondering which way will be the efficient to use(Data is around 50 millions).
Also can you explain the reason.Thanks!!

Comment: Your title should probably be about $elemMatch rather than $match? Anyway, it's usually best to just test it out on your own dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do `query performance` in 3 quick steps:

**Step 1**: Run your queries with explain:

```
db.getCollection('testColl').find({
    "car": { 
        "$elemMatch": {
            "brand": {
                "$in": [                    
                "bmw","audi"           
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}).explain({verbose: true})
```

and

```
db.getCollection('testColl').find({
    "car.brand" :{$in : ["bmw","audi"]}).explain({verbose: true})
```

**Step 2**: [Read about explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)

**Step 3**: Read about each of the methods to understand why exactly the results are as they are

Comment: In fact i had already ran the explain plan and i found only one diff which is: 

For the 1 method, it is filtering and then scanning since we used the $match operator.

For the 2nd method, its directly scanning.

That’s all. This is the only diff that I noticed. The rest of everything is same.

Comment: I think that is your answer pretty much.

Comment: Are you saying that, the second method will be performed well as it will not filter before scan? Please comment. Thanks!!

Comment: Based on the few test I ran the filtering and scanning is somewhat faster so there is difference which would make sense since you first filter then scan. So `elemMatch` performed better in my tests.

Comment: Got it and Thanks you @Akrion